# Marker load time is 10x slower when icon parameter is passed (valid or not)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I found out that when icon is set on marker in google maps, the load time is much slower. It has a significant impact with high amount of markers.

My test environments has 20000 markers.

Creating this amount of markers in that way:

```
   new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng },
      map: this.map,
      draggable: false,
      optimized: true,
      visible: true
    });
```

takes ~400ms. The default icon is used.

but creating markers with added icon parameter (no matter what kind of icon it is):

```
   new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng },
      map: this.map,
      icon: {url: this.iconUrl},
      draggable: false,
      optimized: true,
      visible: true
    });
```

Takes ~4500ms

I tried different kind of icons - svg hardcoded, svg in file, base 64, jpg, png, gif, different kid of sizes - from 50x50px to 1x1px. Everything gives the same result. Even passing icon object with empty url gives the same result of 4500ms load time. Just the fact that we try to use icon, with success or not, slows down the loading time tremendously.

Is there any way to enhance the loading time in such situation?

Fiddle example with comparison of url field as an object and as a string: https://jsfiddle.net/ur76jckb/

Comment: I don't suppose just doing `icon: this.iconUrl` makes any difference?

Comment: Also, what if you set  the `optimized` parameter to false?

Comment: @duncan this is good point! Passing url only makes is as fast as default. I was using an object as I was also setting anchor point and I think this is the only way to do it when creating a marker. I think I will need to create marker first and then change the anchor somehow. Optimised: false makes things worse. If you will create and answet in this thread I will mark it ass accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested setting `icon: this.iconUrl` instead of `icon: {url: this.iconUrl}`, which seemed to speed things up.

Comment: Actually it made a difference as then it was as fast as loading markers with default icon. So the change enhanced the performance. However, creating marker this way makes us unable to set anchor during the marker creation.

Comment: this is super strange for me why this makes so big difference for the google map when creating marker with icon object and icon string if both have url included. Anyhow, as the anchor needs to be added to the marker icon, do you know any other way of setting it outside the icon object?

Comment: @Tukkan did you ever manage to find a way of setting the anchor outside of the icon object when you use a direct url instead of an object?

Comment: @Maeglin77 nope. I tried to bypass this behaviour in various ways with no luck. I created bug in google maps support. They confirmed this behaviour but closed the case with comment that it should work that way. Loading marker with string is fast but you can't add anything else like anchor to it. Loading by object is much slower even if you just set the url only. No sense to me but that is how it is.